# how to do gestures in opengl 3d object in ios

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am doing ios project in opengl concept by using vuforia library(Sample TargetImage).
I want to do pinch gesture and pan gesture in 3d texture.anybody help me how to do this.

Comment: try this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/12667/how-to-rotate-a-3d-object-using-touches-with-opengl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got another SDK "Metaio" and my problem is solved, Inside the camera view we can place the 3D object and we apply gesture on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 ways. 
1) Use touchStart/touchMoved/touchEnd function to get the touch position and manage the pinch to zoom by finding distance between touches.

2) Use UIPinchGesture on the View to get pinch value. This will reduce the pain of calculating the distances etc.

Using the distance you have to either move the camera distance from an object or move the object from the camera.